# AngularJS directive using transclude breaks the $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'am new in AngularJS. I tried to create directive with option `transclude=true` but it seems breaks the $scope. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

      app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.myText = 'Hello';

        $scope.facility = null;
        $scope.facilities = [
          {id:1, name:'One'},
          {id:2, name:'Two'},
          {id:3, name:'Three'}
        ];

        $scope.query = function(){
          console.log($scope.facility, $scope.myText);
        }
      }]);

      app.directive('ohMy', function(){
        return {
          transclude: true,
          template: function(){
            return '<form novalidate><div ng-transclude></div></form>';
          }
        }
      });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <oh-my>
        <input type="text" ng-model="myText"></input>
        <div>{{myText}}</div>
        <select ng-change="query()" ng-model="facility" ng-options="f.name for f in facilities"></select>
      </oh-my>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I changed the textbox value (myText), the text inside div on the next of the textbox showing updated value as I expected. But not when I play with the drop-down -- that the browser's console always showing default values.

When I removed this directive then everything works fine.

What I'm doing wrong in creating the directive? Any idea to fix it?

**-- UPDATE --**

After googling for a while, I found this link: [AngularJS transclude but keep the directive's scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22356067/angularjs-transclude-but-keep-the-directives-scope?rq=1) and try to understand it, then I've modified the directive code to be like this:

```
  app.directive('ohMy', function(){
    return {
      transclude: true,
      template: function(){
        return '<form novalidate><div ng-transclude></div></form>';
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {
        transclude(scope, function(clone) {              
          element.children(0).empty().append(clone);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

And it's working as I expected now. But, any better solution?

Comment: Yes, it's the dot rule. Your model `facility` should be nested in an object. The directive makes a child scope and at that point, you're working with two different `$scope.facility` properties, because the value is a primitive. If you do `foo.facility`, the child scope will inherit `foo`, and then `facility` must be the same for both.

Comment: Thanks, m59! It's working with the dot. But as you said that it is 'rule' so is it something that we can't avoid it? I mean the model inside this directive must be a nested object?

Comment: Some people pretend $scope inheritance doesn't exist and put isolate scopes on all directives, then just pass data explicitly to the directives.

Answer (score -1):

You can try get model from **$parent** scope:

```
      <oh-my>
        <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.myText"></input>
        <div>{{myText}}</div>
        // get model from $parent scope.
        <select ng-change="query()" ng-model="$parent.facility" ng-options="f.name for f in $parent.facilities"></select>
      </oh-my>
```

Link demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/as7dSEybw7PWB24JlPWp?p=preview

Comment: Thanks but no :) - I won't change the HTML part neither controller part, I want to fix the directive.